# jquery & html5 text box save / load from local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Looking to store my text box values to local storage, have them called up upon when page loads, but if no values are typed in (ie. first time app is loaded) I get an error on saying

```
 TypeError: pName is null
 [Break On This Error]  

 if(pName.length>0){
```

JS:

```
$('#form').on("pageinit", function() {
    $('#saveButton').click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem("Name", $('#Name').val());
    });
});


$('#form').on("pageinit", function() {
var pName = localStorage.getItem("Name");    
if(pName.length>0){
$('#Name').val(pName);
} 
});
```

I tried adding this, but it doesn't appear to actually load Enter Name if the value was below 0....

```
$('#form').on("pageinit", function() {
 var pName = localStorage.getItem("Name");

   if(pName.length>0){
        $('#Name').val(pName);
     } else {
        $('#Name').val("Enter name.");
     }
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `if(!pName)` instead of `if(pName.length>0)`, null and the empty string is falsy so it fulfils the condition on not being an empty string and doesn't cause an error if its null.